# amdgpu games aren't HD

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa and I've got a Gigabyte Radeon RX 570 GPU. The OS installed the amdgpu drivers automatically but I can tell a big difference when playing games such as Runescape. I am also using the same exact wallpaper as I was when I had Windows 10 installed and even that wallpaper is noticeably blurry in some spots. When I had the same wallpaper and played Runescape on Windows 10 everything was much more HD and the game also rendered much more smoothly.

Is this just something that I'll have to live with if I continue using Ubuntu or is this something I can fix? I have tried installing open source drivers but I get the same issue. I am also open to buying an NVIDIA GPU if that would help.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, do you plug in the display cable into your GPU slot? or did you set up power cable onto your Graphics card inside the case? Normally, you don't have to do anything and Runescape like an old game even runs without great GPUs, it may run with an Intel CPU onboard graphics of Haswell or better. If you want to know more, please provide your PC specs.